Persist data before ROLLBACK on a SQL Server LOGON Trigger
I have the following logon trigger in SQL Server:
CREATE TRIGGER my_logon_trigger ON ALL SERVER
WITH EXECUTE AS 'SA'
FOR LOGON AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @user_can_logon int;
    .....

    -- Begin Evaluation Process
    -- decide value 0 or 1 for @user_can_logon
    -- Several Inserts of Evaluation Process data into tables
    -- These Inserts are done directly, but also via called Stored Procedures
    -- End Evaluation Process
  
    IF @user_can_logon int <> 1
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
    END;
END;

The "Evaluation Process" is the part where according to user environment context, like, ex, client_host, login_name ..., a decision is taken to allow or not user logon.
The "Inserts" are: debug entries, and cache records (the later for eventual policies/rules) used to speed the process of evaluation.
Problem: the ROLLBACK will rollback the inserts part of the evaluation process.
Is there a way to preserve them (ex. temporary table inside trigger code, or some whatever other way) so that I can insert same information after (!) the ROLLBACK (and this way not loose them)?
PS. This is related with my other question "Logon trigger with both authorization and log insert", but not finding answer there, because in it I was questioning why I was loosing insert - and instructed to put the insert after the rollback, while in this I am asking what can I do since the logic of my solutions needs the inserts to be before the Rollback.

Anything you want persisted to the database needs to happen after the ROLLBACK - anything before that will be rolled back. You can use table variables to hold data that survives a rollback so you have it available to write afterwards. (or variables with strings of JSON could be another way)

Thank You for this Martin.
But in reality, the code part of  "Evaluation Process" does call some Stored Procedures.
If I use a Table Variable in my trigger, can these Stored Procedures write to this Table Variable ?

Didn't you ask this already? What was wrong with that answer

I did. But in the first question I could resolve by putting my insert after the rollback.
Because there I was inserting a single record that would describe the event - user logged in or not allowed to logon.
At this one I cannot put the insert after the rollback, because I am dealing with inserts related to the evaluation process - which must be prior to the decision of letting user logon (no rollback) or letting him not (rollback)
regards
Altin

But do you need these inserts after you deny the login? What exactly are you doing in that evaluation? This sounds very fishy to me. But anyway, did you try to always commit the transaction but then add a THROW... call on failed login? This should prevent logging in i think but i can't test it because i dont' want to be locked out of my systems :)

I have not used any explicit Commit. I have used only Rollback when the "Evaluation Process" has decided that the user is not allowed to logon - because, ex, he is connecting from an unauthorized machine.

Ok, so try it? :)

Random thought - I there some remote SQL execution function available that creates a separate connection that operates outside the transaction?  Something like the made-up EXEC ('INSERT INTO SecurityLog VALUES(''Something is fishy here - I''''m forcing a rollback'')' AT LocalHost IN SEPARATE CONTEXT?
